# Плавное изменение громкости SourceDataLine

Tags: java, аудио

Привет всем в попытках написания  музыкального плеера возникла потребность в плавном изменении громкости звука код рабочий вот только при изменении громкости слышен треск как можно это исправить?

```
public class MainClass {

static FloatControl volume;

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {

    /// Gui
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    JSlider sld = new JSlider();
    frame.setSize(300, 100);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    sld.setMaximum(100);
    sld.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
            VolumeConroller.SetVolume(sld.getValue());

        }
    });

    frame.add(sld);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    File f = new File("Test.wav");
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f);
    AudioFormat form = ais.getFormat();
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, form);
    SourceDataLine Output = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

    Output.open();
    volume = (FloatControl) Output.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
    Output.start();

    VolumeConroller vc = new VolumeConroller();

    byte[] data = new byte[5000];
    int hum = 0;
    while (hum != -1) {
        hum = ais.read(data, 0, data.length);
        Output.write(data, 0, data.length);

    }

  }

}
```

VolumeConroller

```
public class VolumeConroller extends Thread {
static float destvol = 0;
static float curvol = 0;

public VolumeConroller() {
    SetVolume(50);
    this.start();

}

@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {

        if (curvol > destvol + 0.1 || curvol < destvol - 0.1) {

            sleep(4);

            if (destvol > curvol) {
                curvol += 0.1;
            } else {
                curvol -= 0.1;
            }

            MainClass.volume.setValue(curvol);
        } else {
            sleep(300);
        }

    }

}

public static void SetVolume(int d) {
    if (d == 0) {
        destvol = -80;
    } else {
        destvol = Map(d, 0, 100, -50f, 0.3f);
    }

}

public static float Map(float n, float start1, float stop1, float start2, float stop2) {
    return ((n - start1) / (stop1 - start1)) * (stop2 - start2) + start2;
}

static void sleep(int t) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(t);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
}
```